# Google Script onEdit doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this Google Spreadsheet. On cell `A1` of the first sheet, Taskpipes places this formula: `=IMPORTDATA("https://taskpipes.com/temp_file/?token=[my_token]")`. I want to move this formula to the second sheet after this formula has been placed. 
Manually, this works great, but I want this process automated. 
For that I use the `onEdit(e)` function:

```
function onEdit(e){
      console.info("Trigger activated");
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var taskpipes = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var importSheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; 

// CheckCell = Cell where taskpipes places my formula to import the data

      var checkCell = taskpipes.getRange(1,1);
      if (checkCell.isBlank()) {
        console.log("Trigger triggered, no action")
      } else {
        console.log("New file received");

// Copying the formula from taskpipes to importSheet

        var dataLink = taskpipes.getRange(1, 1).getFormula();
        importSheet.getRange(1, 1).setFormula(dataLink);
        checkCell.clear();

// Run the main script

        convertToGWSheet();
      }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doens't work. Also setting triggers with the button  'Triggers for this project' doesn't work.
Anyone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'd use Logger.log instead of console.log since this code is server side. I'd also get taskpipes and importsheet by name.  I also would't run this in an onEdit trigger.  Keep in mind that simple triggers only fire on user actions.

Comment: @Cooper console.log is supported on server side code. See [Class Console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console)

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Do you know that onEdit only is fired when a user makes an edit?

Comment: @Rubén Thanks I didn’t know that

Comment: Is the cell set manualy? `onEdit` will work only if an actual user opens the spreadsheet himself and changes a cell (for example pastes in the function). If a script sets the function, the `onEdit` will **not** trigger as it's meant for **manual** edits.